# How to subset text from an Excel cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have an Excel document with a column full of things that look like this:

`Hume F;Wilhelm K;`

I want to copy this into a blank cell to the right of it, but only what's before the first semicolon. So it would end up looking like this:

`Hume F`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1

Copy  the column, on the copy Text To Columns with `;` as the delimiter and delete the surplus

Option 2

Copy and Paste the entire column then select it Find & Replace, Find what: ;*, Replace All

Option 3

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(";",A1)-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

for example
`=LEFT(A1;SEARCH(";";A1)-1)`